# How to get bounding box coordinates for canvas content?

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I have a canvas with a map. In that canvas the user is able to draw (in red) and the final result will  be:

[image]

After the user as painted whatever he wants I need to calculate the bounding box coordinates of all the content so I could ultimately have:

[image]

Now I can loop through every pixel of the canvas and calculate the bounding box based on every non-empty pixel but this is quite a heavy operation. Any idea of a better logic to achieve the intended results?

Answer (score 2):

You can track what is being drawn and the diameter of the points. Then min/max that for the boundary.

One way to do this is to track position and radius (brush) or boundary (irregular shape) of what is being drawn, then merge that with current min/max bound to update the new bound if needed in effect "pushing" the bounds to always match the interior.

**Example**

```js
var ctx = c.getContext("2d"),
    div = document.querySelector("div > div"),

    // keep track of min/max for each axis
    minX = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER,
    minY = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER,
    maxX = Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER,
    maxY = Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER,
    
    // brush/draw stuff for demo
    radius = 10,
    rect = c.getBoundingClientRect(),
    isDown = false;

ctx.fillText("Draw something here..", 10, 10);
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
c.onmousedown = function() {isDown = true};
window.onmouseup = function() {isDown = false};
window.onmousemove = function(e) {
  if (isDown) {
    var x = e.clientX - rect.left;
    var y = e.clientY - rect.top;
    
    // When something is drawn, calculate its impact (position and radius)
    var _minX = x - radius;
    var _minY = y - radius;
    var _maxX = x + radius;
    var _maxY = y + radius;
    
    // calc new min/max boundary
    if (_minX < minX) minX = _minX > 0 ? _minX : 0;
    if (_minY < minY) minY = _minY > 0 ? _minY : 0;
    if (_maxX > maxX) maxX = _maxX < c.width  ? _maxX : c.width;
    if (_maxY > maxY) maxY = _maxY < c.height ? _maxY : c.height;
    
    // show new bounds
    showBounds();
    
    // draw something
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 6.28);
    ctx.fill();
  }
};

function showBounds() {
  // for demo, using bounds for display purposes (inclusive bound)
  div.style.cssText = 
    "left:" + minX + "px;top:" + minY + 
    "px;width:" + (maxX-minX-1) + "px;height:" + (maxY-minY-1) +
    "px;border:1px solid blue";
}
```

```css
div {position:relative}
div > div {position:absolute;pointer-events:none}
```

```html
<div>
  <canvas id=c width=600 height=600></canvas>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Need to try it out but definitely looks like a great answer! Great job!

Comment: @CarlosAlvesJorge how did it go?

Comment: How can I apply this logic for already drawn images/circle/any shape in canvas? This is my question link :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50136647/draw-rectangle-for-scattered-points