# Draw Rectangle for scattered points

Tags: javascript, math, html5-canvas, geometry

I have some scattered points for which I need to draw a rectangle / circle / polygon as a background. I have only coordinates (x,y) of selected points.what will be the maths formula to this? These points are inside canvas and I need to draw the outer shape for selected points in canvas itself. Tried with canvas rect .
Attaching one more image:
[image]
[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22512319/what-is-aabb-collision-detection?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Thanks for the link . Can you also help me with the formula for minimum bounding box - (BminX–BmaxX, BminY–BmaxY, and BminZ–BmaxZ are the ranges of each exis of the AABB) . I am not understanding how to calculate BminX BmaxX etc.

Comment: minX is the smallest X coordinate of all points, maxX is the largest. Same for Y and Z.