# How do I draw a box around multiple shapes in html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am trying to draw a box around multiple shapes in canvas to say that those shapes are related like a group. 
Tried as below :

```
var ctx = c.getContext("2d"),
radius = 10,
rect = c.getBoundingClientRect(),

ctx.fillText("Draw something here..", 10, 10);
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(250, 300, radius, 0, 6.28);
ctx.fill();
ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(200, 100, radius, 0, 10.28);
ctx.fill();
ctx.fillStyle = "brown";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(350, 210, radius, 0, 10.28);
ctx.fill();

var x = (250+200+350)/3;
var y = (300+100+210)/3;

var radius = Math.sqrt((x1*x1)+(y1*y1));
var _minX = x - radius;
var _minY = y - radius;
var _maxX = x + radius;
var _maxY = y + radius;

ctx.rect(_minX,_minY,(_maxX-_minX+2),(_maxY-_minY+2));
ctx.stroke();
```

But it is not drawing properly.
[How to get bounding box coordinates for canvas content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46528123/how-to-get-bounding-box-coordinates-for-canvas-content?noredirect=1&lq=1) this link explains only for the path not for the existing shapes.
 Below is the image how I want to draw:
[image]

Comment: What exactly is the problem is seems to work?

Comment: No - that image is how I want , not the result I got

Comment: Your code doesn't reflect the shapes you want to be drawn, so it's hard to give you a proper solution for your case. But basically, you would have to store all your shape's BBox in an Array, and then simply get the min_x, max_x, min_y, max_y of all these BBox. This will be the four corners of your group-rect.

Comment: how can I get BBox for each shape? I have only x,y for all those shapes

Comment: Can you please help me with the solution or any reference ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get bounding box coordinates for canvas content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46528123/how-to-get-bounding-box-coordinates-for-canvas-content)

Comment: The searched solution could be this https://stackoverflow.com/a/46528425/1679286

Comment: I have tried those two references. But that is only for the path. But I want to draw for the existing shapes not the path

Comment: Hi Kaiido... I tried min_x min_y max_x max_y concept and drew rect in canvas. Thank you very much . Now I am trying the same thing to draw as a polygon . Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

[Fabric](http://fabricjs.com/) <-- See if this library helps had used this for one of my project it is simple and quick.

Comment: I can look into that library :) But here I need to solve this without using any library.

Answer (score 0):

This Code is not production ready, Or the best solution, but it works in "most cases".

I'm using the imageData, to check for non-white pixel. (If NOT 0 - RGBA Pixel ==> Object) and with this it narrows the possible Rectangle down. You would also need to tweak it, if you don't want the text to be in the Rectangle.

*This code could / **should** be optimized.*

**EDIT:** *Now I am only checking if an Alpha Value is set. And some Random Object creation to test multiple Outcomes*

***Info:*** Objects that are clipped/cut happen, because they are out of the canvas size.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var colors = ["red", "blue", "green", "black"];

ctx.fillText("Draw something here..", 0, 10);

/** CREATEING SOME RANDOM OBJECTS (JUST FOR TEST) **/
createRandomObjects();

function createRandomIntMax(max){
 return parseInt(Math.random() * 1000 * max) % max + 1;
}

function  createRandomObjects(){
 var objectsToDraw = createRandomIntMax(20);
 for(var idx = 0; idx < objectsToDraw; idx++){
  ctx.fillStyle = colors[createRandomIntMax(colors.length)];
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(createRandomIntMax(c.width), createRandomIntMax(c.height), createRandomIntMax(30), 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fill();
 }
}


/** GETTING IMAGE DATA **/
var myImageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, c.width, c.height);

/** FINDING BORDERS **/
findBorders(myImageData.data);

function findBorders(imageData) {

    var result = {
        left: c.width,
        top: c.height,
        right: -1,
        bottom: -1
    }

    var idx = 0;
    var lineLow = -1;
    var lineHigh = -1;
    var currentLine = 0;
    var currentPoint, helper;
    while (idx < imageData.length) {
        currentPoint = imageData[idx + 3]; 

        /** CHECKING FOR OBJECT **/
        if (currentPoint != 0) {

            helper = parseInt(idx % (c.width * 4)) / 4;
            if (lineLow < 0) {
                lineLow = helper;
                lineHigh = helper;
            } else {
                lineHigh = helper;
            }
        }

        if (idx !== 0 && (idx % (c.width * 4)) === 0) {
            currentLine = idx / (c.width * 4);
            // Updating the Border Points
            if (lineLow > -1) {
                result.left = Math.min(lineLow, result.left);
                result.top = Math.min(currentLine, result.top);
                result.right = Math.max(lineHigh, result.right);
                result.bottom = Math.max(currentLine, result.bottom);
            }

            lineLow = -1;
            lineHigh = -1;
        }

        idx += 4;
    }

    ctx.rect(result.left, result.top, result.right - result.left, result.bottom - result.top);
    ctx.stroke()

}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Not iterating through ImageData would be the first and most efficient way to optimize this code.

Comment: True, True, ... but this was the fastes solution I could think of. _(No speed fast)_ ;-)

Comment: Yes, OP would have to rebuild their way of drawing the shapes, we don't have enough to chew on in order to give them a satisfactory solution.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But I cant use this solution as I want to draw outer box for only selected objects in the screen and not for all the objects

Comment: What for type of objects? Circles, Rects, ....? How will the shapes be drawn/created?

Comment: @Sowmya btw. how do you select the objects/shapes?

Comment: I am able to select objects by using jsISO lib. So want to draw box only for selected objects not for all

Answer (score -1):

USE getBoundingClientRect() to get the  exact boundaries

Comment: getBoundingClientRect() of which element? Tried using for canvas . Not sure about the logic for selected shapes :(